# Multiple filter query using Zend Db

Tags: mysql, zend-db

I would like to create a price and category filter using PHP and Zend Db. Works perfectly when filter independently by price or category

How to generate following query using Zend DB

```
SELECT * FROM `products`  WHERE 
    (
        (price >= '1000') AND (price <= '1500 ')
        OR 
        (price >= '1500') AND (price <= '2000 ') 
    ) 
    AND (category_id = '2')
```

Tried as follows,

```
$this->where('price > ?', '1000')->where('price < ?', '1500');
$this->orwhere('price > ?', '1500')->where('price < ?', '2000');

$this->where('category > ?', '2');
```

but it generates,

```
SELECT * FROM `products`  WHERE 
    (price >= '1000') AND (price <= '1500 ')
OR 
    (price >= '1500') AND (price <= '2000 ') 
AND (category_id = '2')
```

Any idea?

Comment: In this case it is just `$this->where('price > ?', '1000')->where('price < ?', '2000');
$this->where('category > ?', '2');`

Comment: its just a demo. prices are not in manual order :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->where("
              (price >= '1000') AND (price <= '1500 ') 
              OR (price >= '1500') AND (price <= '2000 ')"
);   
$this->where("category_id =?", 2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, this will create query as SELECT * FROM `products`  WHERE 
   ( (price >= '1000') AND (price <= '1500 '))
OR 
  (  (price >= '1500') AND (price <= '2000 ') )
AND (category_id = '2')

Comment: I change it. try it. I think it is not perfect answer. But it is working.

Comment: yea... its working . thanks genius. sometimes solutions are better than perfect answer :-)